# How can I link a task In OneNote to a Sharepoint shared task list?

Tags: workflow-tasks-list, onenote

When I add a task in OneNote 2016 Desktop via the Outlook Tasks Menu, this creates a task in my personal Outlook task list, but I want it in a task list from my Sharepoint that I have linked into Outlook. What I want is

- the task to show on Sharepoint for my team members, in OneNote so I can see the context of the task (for instance, taken as an action during a meeting, and zes of course, the OneNote notebook is also online)
- mark complete actions to be passed on from Sharepoint to OneNote

I can create a task via OneNote in my personal Outlook task list and then copy it to the Sharepoint list. However, these tasks are then copies, and changing one, for instance marking it complete, does not affect the other. Perhaps a little VBA or similar can help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe SharePoint and OneNote share this particular feature like SharePoint does with Outlook. OneNote is simply for taking notes, if you want users to interact with the tasks I would add a link to the task list in OneNote.

The only idea I have is that you could export a view from your task list into Excel, save it in SharePoint and then use the Insert > Spreadsheet option in OneNote to display the spreadsheet. I haven't tested it but it might be worth testing out, I don't think it would automatically refresh so that could be an issue.

Comment: I find a link to a the Sharepoint task list in OneNote not so useful since I want to create and assign tasks mainly during meetings, so I want to retain the meeting's contextual information for the task.

Comment: Well you can either record tasks in OneNote and have someone else put them in a task list or you can open the task list and do it from there. Either way the point of task list is to keep track of who is doing what. It is up to you where you want everyone to keep track of the information.